# Usare bene la 'o' per contrapporre efficacemente opzioni ritenute mutuamente escludentisi

Tags: grammar, conjunctions

> a) Uno o è cattolico o è comunista, that's all.
>
> b) Uno è cattolico o comunista, that's all.

Spesso soggiunge l'esigenza di asserire concetti secondo i quali esistono solo due opzioni alternative, di talché ricorre l'uso della 'o' per indicare—anche a fini contrappositivi—ciò.

Che sappia, in tali casi gli italiani usano anche "delle due, l'una: o X o Y", dove, p.e., X potrebbe essere 'zuppa' e Y 'pan bagnato'.

Io sono in difficoltà con la 'o' quando devo usarla come in a) perché "Uno o"—cioè la 'o' che segue 'Uno'—appare, quantomeno a me, strana.

Stante ciò, tendo ad usare forme come la b) anche laddove preferirei la a) perché dà una maggiore idea di contrapposizione.

Domande:

- Secondo la grammatica italiana, la a) è corretta quanto la b)?
- Se sono entrambe grammaticalmente corrette, c'è una ragione per cui uno, in dipendenza del contesto, dovrebbe preferire l'una all'altra?

Comment: "Spesso  soggiunge l'esigenza di asserire concetti...", pensi che sia un italiano corrente o sei consapevole di esprimerti in maniera eccentrica?

Comment: Rispondo se prima formuli una riscrittura alternativa della frase, @Josh61.

Comment: "capita spesso di dover esprimere concetti..."

Comment: If you are satisfied with one of the answers to your question, please consider the option to "accept" an answer by clicking a checkmark next to that answer.

Answer (score 4):

La differenza tra `a)` e `b)` risiede nell'origine della loro struttura.

Le `o...o` in `a)` sono quelle latine di `aut ..aut`, di cui oggi conosciamo il significato con l'operazione logica XOR.
La `o`in `b)` deriva dalla `vel` latina, di cui oggi conosciamo l'operazione logica OR.

Quando si intende dire che la verità è una soltanto, che non ci può essere ambiguità, che non ci sono altre alternative, che le possibili soluzioni si escludono a vicenda allora si usa XOR: `o nero o bianco`,`o paghi l'affitto o te ne vai`, `o getti la pistola o sparo`, `o la colonna regge o il soffitto crolla`. In genere si usa in contesti importanti e delicati, proprio per via della forza dell'affermazione; è molto usato nei discorsi "teatrali" perchè capace di convicere che si tratti o di vita o di morte.

Quando la verità è incerta o non è costretta a ricadere nelle scelte che proponiamo (come il più delle volte nella vita ordinaria) allora si usa OR: `vado al mare o in montagna?`,`vuole la pasta o la minestra? (ma se le vuole entrambe può mangiarle entrambe!)`.

Comment: Benvenuta su Italian.SE, @Sandra!

Comment: E io contesto la contestazione, @kos. Non mi sembra che la congiunzione “o” sia per forza uno XOR. Anzi, la Treccani stessa, nella [voce relativa alla congiunzione “o”](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/o1/) specifica che può avere «valore inclusivo, come nella frase *di solito, la sera leggo o guardo la televisione* (dove non è escluso il caso in cui si faccia l’una e l’altra cosa)».

Comment: Hai ragione @DaG, non è vero che "o" è sempre disgiuntivo, ovviamente ritratto il "sempre"; però ragionevolmente non mi sembra che sia il caso della domanda, il valore di "o" in "Uno è cattolico o comunista, that's all." mi sembra palesemente disgiuntivo.

Comment: @kos Ritengo anch'io che in quella frase l'“o” sia disgiuntivo (con buona pace dei “cattocomunisti”...), ma ritengo pure che bisognerebbe fare uno sforzo per mantenere vivo il valore inclusivo, proprio per arginare cose buffe come “e/o”.

Comment: @DaG Mi unisco alla crociata. Comunque @ Sandra non per sembrare insistente e ripetermi, voglio solo ritrattare quello che ho detto; *nella fattispecie* non mi sembra che sia un OR, visto che il significato inteso credo sia di "Uno o è cattolico o è comunista, that's all." (o XOR / "aut") in entrambi i casi (che se ci pensi è l'accezione di "o" più comune).

Answer (score 0):

Uh. In veste di informatico / logico adoro questo problema.

In generale, la questione non è definita: nell'uso colloquiale la gente tende ad usare le due forme (doppia o VS singola o) in modo intercambiabile per entrambi i significati di OR e XOR, addirittura a volte usato persino come NAND: "Eh no! ti compro [o] i gormiti o il videogioco [implicito -> o niente]"

***Tendenzialmente*** la forma con doppia o (o A o B) viene usata più come XOR, mentre la singola o come OR ("Vuoi un primo o un secondo?" -> o entrambi), come specificato da Sandra.

Un altro punto interessante a questo riguardo è l'uso dell'"ovvero". In contesto colloquiale "ovvero" viene usato per introdurre una spiegazione di qualcosa, ma in contesto legale (i.e. tribunali, trascrizioni, testi legislativi, etc.) l'"ovvero" sta ad indicare esattamente il connettivo logico OR ("Il proprietario di un tratto di strada, ovvero di passo carraio, è tenuto al suo mantenimento").

La questione in realtà è più ampia: i linguaggi naturali sono ambigui, e le ambiguità sui connettivi logici sono una delle classi di ambiguità più comuni in assoluto, in quasi tutte le lingue.

In altre parole, segui il tuo istinto :) Nessuna delle due forme è fondamentalmente scorretta.